# iOS (Swift): Core data transformable attributes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nscoding, transformable

I have a simple `Time` class that adopts `NSCoding` protocol:

```
class Time: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var hours: Int

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.hours, forKey: "hours")
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let hours = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "hours") as? Int
            else { return nil }
        self.hours = hours
    }

    init(hours: Int) {
        self.hours = hours
    }

}
```

which I want to be a `Transformable` attribute to my `Watch` entity:

```
final class Watch: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public fileprivate(set) var time: Time
}
```

as shown here:

[image]

I successfully save this to the managed object context but when I reload the app the `time` attribute is `nil`.

Am I missing something here? Why doesn't this property successfully save? This seems to be all that is required in other posts.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion in the comments of the question by @IraniyaNaynesh is a red herring.

The answer turns out to be quite simple. Change `decodeObject` to `decodeInteger` in the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method and the data restores the `BLOBS`, which are **not** `nil` and have been saved successfully, from the SQLite database.